# How to influence the default URL scheme from url or hyperref?

Tags: urls, komacv

I am using `komacv` in an attempt to typeset a CV which I originally wrote with `moderncv`. As far as I can tell `hyperref` gets loaded by `komacv`, which in turn causes `url` to be loaded. But I don't know which of the two may be responsible for the behavior.

Consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[paper=A4]{komacv}
\renewcommand*{\firstname}{John}
\renewcommand*{\familyname}{Doe}
\renewcommand*{\homepage}{tex.stackexchange.com}
\hypersetup{hidelinks}
\setkomafont{addressfont}{\scriptsize\sffamily}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

When generating a PDF from this, the `tex.stackexchange.com` will point to `http://tex.stackexchange.com`. So evidently there is a mechanism to cause a host name without URL scheme to be converted to a link using `http://` as its default URL scheme (i.e. protocol). How can I change this to point to `https://tex.stackexchange.com` instead?

I realize that in many cases the `http://` address will redirect to `https://` but that's merely a convention and so it would be desirable to influence the automatism embedded in either `hyperref` or `url`.

Comment: What if you type `https://tex.stackexchange.com` in your document instead of `tex.stackexchange.com`? Wouldn't this solve the problem directly?

Comment: @Superuser27 not really, because aesthetically that be inferior (it's longer and more clutter in a CV). Technically it would be one pragmatic solution, though, agreed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass[paper=A4]{komacv}
\renewcommand*{\firstname}{John}
\renewcommand*{\familyname}{Doe}
\renewcommand*{\homepage}{tex.stackexchange.com}
\hypersetup{hidelinks}

%re-renew the relevant cv definition
\renewcommand*{\httplink}[2][]{%
\ifstrempty{#1}{%
\href{https://#2}{\usefontofkomafont{httplinkfont}#2}}{%
\href{https://#2}{\usefontofkomafont{httplinkfont}#1}}%
}

\setkomafont{addressfont}{\scriptsize\sffamily}
\begin{document}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```